# Maven: ant-run plugin echo does not seem to execute

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I have a maven project that is using the ant-run plugin.  I added an echo message but it does not seem to execute:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <id>ast-application-deployment-kit</id>
                         <phase>package</phase>
                         <goals>
                              <goal>run</goal>
                         </goals>
                         <configuration>
                             <target>
                                 <echo message="Starting ant-run target configuration."/>
```

But when I `mvn clean package`, I see this

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (my-app) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO] Executed tasks
```

But I do not see the echo.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Consider upgrading your plugin version to the latest (1.8):

This POM snippet prints echo:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <echo>NOW YOU CAN SEE ME!</echo>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```